# Maven 2.0.8 or later on Redhat Enterprise Linux

Tags: maven-2, rhel

I saw an error message during my maven build

```
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Error resolving version for 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin': Plugin requires Maven version 2.0.8
```

I guess that means I have to upgrade my maven2 (currently at 2.0.7) to 2.0.8 or later.

My maven2 was installed following [the instruction](http://www.jpackage.org/yum.php) of JPackage.org and I am using their 5.0 Repo.  My machine is a Redhat Enterprise Linux 5

However, I could not find maven2 at 2.0.8 or later from there.

Comment: How about using their 6.0 repo, which has an [upgraded](http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/jpackage/6.0/generic/free/repoview/maven2.html) maven?

Comment: Their 6.0 does not have 2.0.8 and later either.  Furthermore, to make thing even more confusing, they add an RPM for "maven22" (with two "2") in the name and I think it is for maven 2.2.1.  But I don't know what is the relationship of this maven22 package with the original (but pretty old) mave2 (2.0.7) RPM package.  I later decided to just manually install maven2 without using RPM at all (see my other answers).

Answer (score 1):

Forget about RPM, JPackage, and yum ... I finally decided to install maven2 (2.2.1) manually (not using an RPM at all)

The installation [steps listed](http://maven.apache.org/download.html) on the maven.apache.org website are very straightforward, and all the files on maven is localized under one direction under (e.g)

/usr/local/apache-maven-2.2.1

After that, end users only need to make a few lines in his/her ~/.bash_profile, and that is it.

```
export M2_HOME=/usr/local/apache-maven-2.2.1
export M2=$M2_HOME/bin
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/default
PATH=$M2:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH:$HOME/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always download and install Maven manually from [the Maven download page](http://maven.apache.org/download.html) . That page also has installation instructions after the download list.